# how to open list form in new window instead of dialog? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have the following line of code which shows me the dialog of my list:

```
<a href="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('http://mysite/Lists/mylist/NewForm.aspx');">Add New Item</a>
```

but instead of dialog I want to open a new window for `NewForm` of my list.

How can I make this via JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove

```
javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('');
```

to be like

```
<a href="http://mysite/Lists/mylist/NewForm.aspx" target="_blank">Add New Item</a>
```

Using `target="_blank"` : to Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

**[Update]**

based on your request at comments ,

Use the following code and change the `height` and `width`

For more details, check the detail steps at [Open a link via Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

```
<script>
function openDialog(pageUrl) {
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Title of the Dialog',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
width: 500,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('http://SharePointSite/Lists/WebEvents/NewForm.aspx');">Central Admin</a>
```

Comment: yes but I need to be just like dialog with custom width and height

Comment: Please , Check my updated answer