# SharePoint appends IsDlg=1 parameter to URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, apple-ios

we want to open a form in a dialogue by using "isdlg=1". When I apply this within the URL it automatically appends "IsDlg=1" to the end of the URL and as a result the form doesn't scroll on mobile devices. I have to manually remove the appended "&IsDlg=1" every time.

We would prefer to use Safari Browser on iPads, but also have the SharePoint app and have the same result on both.

Note: it works fine on an Android device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the query parameter `IsDlg=1` is not enough to cause the form to be loaded in a dialog. This query parameter is just a flag that causes other CSS and JavaScript on the page to behave as if it's a dialog.

To actually launch to the form in a dialog, you need some JavaScript and to call `SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog`. `ShowPopupDialog` will actually launch the form in a dialog, and append `IsDlg=true` to the URL, causing it to behave as if it's in a dialog.

Ref: [how to open list form in new window instead of dialog? SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192447/how-to-open-list-form-in-new-window-instead-of-dialog-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thanks Joe, a problem we have is that the form (FlowForma form) and it's lauch page are locked down to custom code on our tenancy by FlowForma themselves. Why does the launch as dialog work ok on non iOS devices?

Comment: I don't have an IOS device to test on, but my guess would be that different CSS is loaded on IOS/Safari, and that CSS is setting overflow to hidden when IsDlg=1.